# Rendering CustomUser Signup Form - How to get the Password Field

Tags: django-models, django-forms

I am rendering a CustomUser Sign Up form in a particular URL. While I could get the password field to work in form.as_p, I am struggling to replicate the form field when rendering each form field individually.

I have tried to render form.password and form.password1 but they are not working.

Following is the section of my signup.html.  PLEASE NOTE `{{ form.as_p}}` does the job.

```
      {{ form.unit_floor.errors }}
      <label for="{{ form.unit_floor.id_for_label }}">Unit No: # . 
      </label>
      {{ form.unit_floor }}
      {{ form.unit_unit.errors }}
      <label for="{{ form.unit_floor.id_for_label }}"> - </label>
      {{ form.unit_unit }}
    </div>
    <div class=“fieldWrapper”>
      {{ form.password.errors }}
      <label for="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}">Password: </label>
      {{ form.password }}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this stuff out.  Thanks to the Django Documentation.  The point was to add the following in the CustomUser creation class:

```
password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

Be sure to import `from django import forms`